# Reverse position of MongoDB items (mongoose)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is there any way to invert the position of items in mongoDB?

[image]

thanks

Comment: Object properties have no "order" per se. At least there is no reason to rely on it. Why would you need it? Looks like [The XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: You cannot control the order of the fields in a MongoDB document - except that at the root document where the `_id` field will be the _first_ field, always.

Comment: When I add another category in Schema, it is below __v, so I wanted to modify it.
I thought I could change it.
Thanks for the replies.

Comment: Any specific use case that you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Order of fields in MongoDB is **preserved** [see this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#field-order-in-write-operations)
MongoDB also uses this order to [compare documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-type-comparison-order/#objects)

One other thing you can do is `$replaceRoot` to pick the order you like in your results.

For example
Data
`[{"a" : 1, "b" : 2}]`
Query
`aggregate([{"$replaceRoot":{"newRoot":{"b":"$b", "a":"$a"}}}])`
Results
 `[{"b": 2,"a": 1}]`

I think you shouldn't rely on it and avoid using it and use documents as hash-maps in general, but if you need it MongoDB keeps it or you can construct the order you need, with query like above.